# Bitwise Operations on a 16 bit number

Tags: c++

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a 16 bit int and set/maniuplate all the individual bits. What would the code be if I want my int to start out with all 16 bits = 0?

If I declare my int as

```
int16_t bitNum = 0;
```

Is this the same as 0000000000000000? And how do I access the values of the individual bits? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Read about bitwise operations: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: Also, never use signed types for bitwise operations; their behavior under bit manipulations is too poorly defined. `uint16_t` is the type to use here.

Comment: long story short: you usually (warning: i'm generalizing!) set the bits with `|` (unary OR) and unset them with `&` (unary AND)

Comment: to get the bits, use `&`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/1227469

Comment: Didn't see the duplicate, thanks for the help and the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an object of an integral type to zero means setting all its used bits to zero.

You could write two functions. one will set a specified bit (starting from 0) and other will reset a specified bit. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

inline uint16_t & set( uint16_t &bitNum, size_t n )
{
    return ( bitNum |= 1 << n );
}

inline uint16_t & reset( uint16_t &bitNum, size_t n )
{
    return ( bitNum &= ~( 1 << n ) );
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t bitNum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << set( bitNum, i ) << std::endl;
        reset( bitNum, i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
```

The other way is to use standard class `std::bitset` declared in header `<bitset>` It already has the corresponding functions.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<16> bitNum;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << bitNum.set( i ) << std::endl;
        bitNum.reset( i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0000000000000001
0000000000000010
0000000000000100
0000000000001000
0000000000010000
0000000000100000
0000000001000000
0000000010000000
0000000100000000
0000001000000000
0000010000000000
0000100000000000
0001000000000000
0010000000000000
0100000000000000
1000000000000000
```

Enjoy!:)

Comment: what corresponding function?

Comment: This is much cleaner than what I was doing, the set and reset functions are a good idea, thanks.

Comment: @cjw They correspond to the similar functions in std::bitset. So it is a good approach to write these functions as I showed.

Comment: Or you can create a macro:
#define _bv(a) (1 << a);

Answer (score 4):

> Is this the same as 0000000000000000?

Yes.

> And how do I access the values of the individual bits?

You cannot access real individual bit as the smaller variable computer can address and allocate is a `char` (a char variable is of the natural size to hold a character on a given machine). But you can manipulate each bit using bit masks ( and bitwise operations)

```
temp & (1 << N) // this will test N-th bit
```

or in C++ you can use `std::bitset` to represent a sequence of bits.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t temp = 0x0;
    std::bitset< 16>   bits( temp);

    // 0 -> bit 1
    // 2 -> bit 3
    std::cout << bits[2] << std::endl;
}
```

This is what Bjarne Stroustrup says about operations on bits in "C++ Prog... 3d edition" 17.5.3 Bitset:

> C++ supports the notion of small sets of flags efficiently through
>   bitwise operations on integers (§6.2.4). These operations include **&**
>   (and), **|** (or), **^** (exclusive or), **<<** (shift left), and **>>** (shift
>   right).

Well, also **~**, bitwise complement operator, the tilde, that flips every bit.

> Class bitset generalizes this notion and offers greater
>   convenience by providing operations on a set of N bits indexed from 0
>   through N-1, where N is known at compile time. For sets of bits that
>   don’t fit into long int using a bitset is much more convenient than
>   using integers directly. For smaller sets, there may be an efficiency
>   tradeoff. If you want to name the bits, rather than numbering them,
>   using a **set** (§17.4.3), an **enumeration** (§4.8), or a **bitfield** (§C.8.1)
>   are alternatives. (...) A key idea in the design of bitset is that an optimized implementation can be provided for bitsets that fit in a single word. The interface reflects this assumption.

So there are alternatives, i.e another option is to use a *bitfields*. They are binary variables bundled together as fields in a struct. You can then access each individual "bit" using access operator: . for references or -> for pointers.

```
struct BitPack {
    bool b1 :  0;
    bool b2 :  0;
    //...
    bool b15 : 0;
};

void f( BitPack& b)
{
  if( b.b1) // if b1 is set
      g();
}
```

links:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field